# File save upload doesn't replace existing file despite FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE

Tags: 7, forms, files

I'm trying to force replacement of existing file with same name, if a new version is uploaded by user. I've seen a lot of posts about this topic but none that I could find addresses how to force the replacement.

I'm using a custom form, and here's the code I've been trying to make work during the form validation:

```
  $file = file_save_upload(
      'file', 
      array(
        'file_validate_is_document' => array(), // Validates file is really a document.
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc ppt pps avi mpg mov wmv'), // Validate extensions.
      ),
      'public://',
      FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE
  );
```

The revised file (let's say "file.jpg") is uploaded, but inevitably Drupal creates a new copy and renames it file_0.jpg, file_1.jpg, etc for each new version.

I even tried to programmatically delete the original file using "file_delete" prior to committing the upload but I still get the copy!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is drupal's default behaviour and a known issue. It has been addressed a couple of ways.

The [Upload File Replace](http://drupal.org/project/upload_replace) module addresses this issue by swapping the filenames so the new file retains the original name.

The [Media Update](http://drupal.org/project/media_update) module allows in situ replacement of media files (part of the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) project).

You could either make use of one of these modules, or use them as a model for your own function.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @triskelion for all the options. I ended up using the Upload File Replace.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using the following code.

```
$file = file_save_upload('file', $validators);
// If the file passed validation:
if ($file) {
    // I PLACED IT IN THE NEXT LINE
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)) {
        // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
        $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    } else {
        form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file to the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
} else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_temp = file_save_data($attachment->data, 'public://<my_files_locatioin>/<my-filename.pdf>' , FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```