# Ensuring Users Get the Most Up-to-Date PDF

Tags: webforms

I have taken over a Drupal 7 site that contains a lot of pdf forms. These forms are frequently updated. Many of these forms were uploaded to sites/default/files/userfiles and manually linked across the site.

To prevent having to track down each link, when I update a form I have been replacing the file using the same filename. This naturally isn't a great solution because people are loading the old versions from cache locally.

Is there a simple solution I am overlooking?

Note: I am using the media module for new forms going forward, but wonder if there is a solution for the old files that were done "improperly" as it were.

Comment: Cache bust the URLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File save upload doesn't replace existing file despite FILE\_EXISTS\_REPLACE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68250/file-save-upload-doesnt-replace-existing-file-despite-file-exists-replace)

Comment: In the linked question the accepted answer offers two solutions. To use the media module probably is the most sustainable solution. You then don't link files anymore, you link media entities (in which files simply can be replaced).

Comment: Thanks laymannx. I am using the media module for new forms going forward, but was wondering if there was a solution for the old files that were done "improperly" as it were.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to add a cache bust query string on the end of the file URL, the same way they are added to assets in the head of each page. This tells the browser to fetch it as well as bypass any other caching layers you may have.